# Failed to start PowerDNS Authoritative server

Tags: powerdns

use systemctl restart pnds command system said me you should use to systemctl status pnds ı show this fail message . I saw code=exited, status=1/failure do you have any idea ?

ı can create succesfull database ı wrote some mysql quary. I can see my table in mysql and later ı try install pdns and installed but later ı saw this error code

```
oot@goktug-virtual-machine:/home/goktug# journalctl -xe
Automatic restarting of the unit pdns.service has been scheduled, as the result for
the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
Ağu 15 16:25:36 goktug-virtual-machine systemd[1]: Stopped PowerDNS Authoritative Server.
Subject: A stop job for unit pdns.service has finished
Defined-By: systemd
Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support

A stop job for unit pdns.service has finished.

The job identifier is 195344 and the job result is done.
Ağu 15 16:25:36 goktug-virtual-machine systemd[1]: Starting PowerDNS Authoritative Server...
Subject: A start job for unit pdns.service has begun execution
Defined-By: systemd
Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support

A start job for unit pdns.service has begun execution.

The job identifier is 195344.
Ağu 15 16:25:36 goktug-virtual-machine pdns_server[14698]: Loading '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pdns/libgmysqlbackend.so'
Ağu 15 16:25:36 goktug-virtual-machine pdns_server[14698]: Unable to load module '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pdns/libgmysqlbackend.so': /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pdns/libgmysqlback>
Ağu 15 16:25:36 goktug-virtual-machine pdns_server[14698]: DNSBackend unable to load module in gmysql
Ağu 15 16:25:36 goktug-virtual-machine systemd[1]: pdns.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Subject: Unit process exited
Defined-By: systemd
Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support

An ExecStart= process belonging to unit pdns.service has exited.

The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
Ağu 15 16:25:36 goktug-virtual-machine systemd[1]: pdns.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Subject: Unit failed
Defined-By: systemd
Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support

The unit pdns.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Ağu 15 16:25:36 goktug-virtual-machine systemd[1]: Failed to start PowerDNS Authoritative Server.
Subject: A start job for unit pdns.service has failed
Defined-By: systemd
Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support

A start job for unit pdns.service has finished with a failure.

The job identifier is 195344 and the job result is failed.

gnu/pdns/libgmysqlbackend.so'
/x86_64-linux-gnu/pdns/libgmysqlbackend.so': /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pdns/libgmysqlbackend.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
e in gmysql
=exited, status=1/FAILURE

code'.

Server.

ESCOC

nd.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

ESCOC

my command;
Launch=gmysql 
gmysql-host=localhost
gmysql-user=goktug
gmysql-password=xxxxx
gmydwl-dbname=powerdns
```

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Welcome and thank you for posting. Getting good answers requires a clear and useful question which is [well written](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3609/37681) , [on-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) and contains sufficient details to provide you with a good solution. Only a  statement and missing actual error message is not enough. Post relevant errors from any pdns log files and/or relevant `journalctl -xe` messages. - Please improve your question to address those points or run the risk of leaving your problem unresolved and/or having your question closed.

Comment: Thank you for updating your question.  When posting console output / settings, please format that text  as "`code`" using [Markdown](https://serverfault.com/editing-help) and/or the formatting options in the edit menu to properly type-set your posts. That improves readability, attracts better answers  and allows indexing by search engines, which may help people with similar questions. And that will allow people willing to answer your question to also easily copy-and-paste your commands/settings/error messages into their answer.

Comment: The error  `Unable to load module '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pdns/libgmysqlbackend.so': /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pdns/libgmysqlback` suggests that you're trying to use a backend `gmysql` which is not (correctly) installed. Depending on how you installed PowerDNS you may need to (separately) install the correct backend support.  - Also this directive  `gmydwl-dbname=` looks like typo

Comment: Can you give me solve algorithm with command ?